# [emberjs]what's point of adding 'on("init")' to observabes?

Tags: ember.js

I'm learning ember-cli-101. It adds on('init') when using observer. I tried to delete it , and it makes no difference. 
I tried to read the api document and still make no sense, please help me out...

```
autoSave: function() {
    var article = this.get('article');

    if (!article.get('isNew')) {
        this.sendAction('save', article);
    }
},
stateChanged: function() {
    var article = this.get('article');

    if (article.get('isDirty') && !article.get('isSaving')) {
        Ember.run.once(this, this.autoSave);
    }
}.on('init').observes('article.state')

autoSave:.....
stateChanged: function() {
    var article = this.get('article');

    if (article.get('isDirty') && !article.get('isSaving')) {
        Ember.run.once(this, this.autoSave);
    }
}.observes('article.state')
```

They really works the same, what's the difference...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the property is changed before the observer is initialized, the observer won't fire. This is why sometimes it is good to run fire the observer function also on init.

Comment: Yes, the book says so. But there isn't anywhere run the method "state Changed", why and when the observer is initialized?

Comment: stateChanged method is fired automatically by observer. on initialization of the controller/route or whatever it is, and when this.article.save property is changed

Comment: I mean if I delete the "on('init')" part. When is the observer initialized?

Comment: Observer is initialized (starting watching) when the 'this' object (controller/route/component/view) is initialized. When you delete the on('init') part, observer will NOT fire on initialization, but will wait for the changes in the 'article.state'. If the 'article.state' is set or changed BEFORE the initialization, the observer will not fire this time, only on next changes.